# What determines which SQL queries are displayed in the Spark SQL UI

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to figure out why activity that I *know* is occurring isn't showing up in the SQL tab of the Spark UI. I am using Spark 1.6.0.

For example, we have a load of activity occurring today between 11:06 & 13:17, and I know for certain that the code being executed is using Spark dataframes API:
[image: Spark Job UI]

Yet if I hop over to the SQL tab I don't see any activity occurring for between those times:
[image: Spark SQL UI]

So...I'm trying to figure out what influences whether not activity appears in that SQL tab, because the information presented in that SQL tab is (arguably) the most useful information in the whole UI - and when there's activity occurring that isn't showing up it becomes kinda annoying. The only distinguishing characteristic seems to be that the jobs that are showing up in the SQL tab use actions that don't write any data (e.g. count()), the jobs that do write data don't seem to be showing up. I'm puzzled as to why.
Any pearls of wisdom?

Comment: You're using 1.6.0 which is "terribly" old and doubt many could help. Is there a chance to give 2.2.0 a shot and see if things got better?

Comment: Yeah we're stuck with it for the time being because that's what our appliance vendor supports unfortunately.